# HttpWebRequests Returning error from Youtube

Tags: asp.net

I cannot seem to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

My code below keeps returning a 400 code from youtube....

```
If Not Page.Request.QueryString("code") Is Nothing Then
            Dim code As String = "code=" & Page.Request.QueryString("code") & "&client_id=myclientid&client_secret=mysecret&redirect_uri=http://localhost:61163/Testing/YoutubeAPI.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code"
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
        Dim byteData As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code)
        With request
            .Method = "POST"
            .ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            .ContentLength = byteData.Length
        End With

        Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        requestStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        requestStream.Close()

        Dim WebResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim responseStream As Stream = WebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            If Not line Is Nothing Then
                sb.Append(line)
            End If
        End Using


    End If
```

the error occurs at request.GetRequestStream()...  the best I can figure out at this stage is that google doesn't like what i'm asking for but cannot seem to find out why?

(My client ID and secret have been swopped incidentally....)

Comment: Does it help when you Flush the request stream just after you write to it?

Comment: Hi Wiktor.. am afraid I'm swimming in the deep end here without my water wings.. what do you mean? :)

Comment: requestStream.Flush() before Close()

Comment: hey Wiktor thanks for your help :) the problem lay in the url encoding of my content string :) sorted. wonder if I can answer my own question hahaha :)

Answer (score 0):

well am not sure if the etiquette is correct here in answering my own question but you may find it useful nonetheless.

The answer lay in the URL encoding of content string...

so now slightly amended the awesomeness of OAuth2 is unleashed and I can get pretty much whatever I want from the youtube API :) (although NO thanks to the black hole rabbit-hole of google documentation...

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.Request.QueryString("code") Is Nothing Then
        Dim Token As String = CodeTrade("code=" & Server.UrlEncode(Page.Request.QueryString("code")) & "&redirect_uri=" & Server.UrlEncode("http://localhost:61163/Testing/YoutubeAPI.aspx") & "&client_id=xxx=&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=authorization_code")

        'now i CAN do something with the magical and elusive access_token from this point forward....
    End If
End Sub
Public Shared Function CodeTrade(code As String) As String
    Dim apiResponse As String

    Dim postData As String = code

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"), HttpWebRequest)

    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    apiResponse = DirectCast(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription.ToString()

    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)

    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    Return responseFromServer
End Function
```